# Storing and returning local pointers from within a 2D char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc
#include <string.h> // strlen

char** _malloc_2D_array (char** arg_2D_array,
                         int rows,
                         int cols,
                         int type)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    if (type == 0)
    {
        arg_2D_array = malloc(sizeof(char**) * rows);
        for (; i < rows; i++)
        {
            arg_2D_array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * cols);
        }
    }
    return arg_2D_array;
}

char** _strtok (char* arg_string, const char* arg_delimeter)
{
    char** after_tokenization      = _malloc_2D_array (after_tokenization, 10, 20, 0);
    char*  hold_chars_of_one_group = malloc(sizeof(char*) * strlen(arg_string));

    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while (arg_string[i])
    {
        if (arg_string[i] != *arg_delimeter)
        {
            hold_chars_of_one_group[k] = arg_string[i];
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            after_tokenization[j] = hold_chars_of_one_group;
            j++;
            k = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return after_tokenization;
}

int main()
{
    char** p = _strtok ("anisha,kaul,shizuka,sharma", ",");
    printf ("-%s- p is being printed:", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
`-sharmaa- p is being printed`

I was expecting all the words rather than the last one. Also, one extra `a` has been appended with the word which is printed. Why?

This line:

`after_tokenization[j] = hold_chars_of_one_group;`

seems to be overwriting addresses in the 2D array even though I am incrementing the index. Why?

Comment: `after_tokenization[j]` is an uninitialized pointer. You need to allocate space for it.

Comment: Why? Haven't I allocated space for it in the first line of the program? Is that wrong? @RoadRunner

Comment: You have a severe abuse of pointer types here. Turn on compiler warnings and heed them. Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `char** after_tokenization      = malloc(sizeof(char**) * 1000);` @RoadRunner Is this wrong?

Comment: @AquariusTheGirl You allocated space for `**after_tokenization`, not `after_tokenization[j]`.

Comment: Can you explain that in detail as an answer. What is the difference between two? @RoadRunner

Comment: @RoadRunner I have allocated memory now, see edit. But, the result has not changed. Why?

Comment: @AquariusTheGirl Sorry I will try and give a detailed answer now. The one below is also pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    char** after_tokenization      = _malloc_2D_array (after_tokenization, 10, 20, 0);
```

When `_malloc_2D_array` is called, `after_tokenization` is still uninitialized. `_malloc_2D_array` cannot use its value. This argument is fully redundant. Do you pass a pointer to `malloc`? No, malloc returns a pointer to you. `_malloc_2D_array` is no different. Indeed, `_malloc_2D_array` is not using the value of `arg_2D_array`, but immediately proceeds to assign a new value to it. IOW, it is nothing but a local variable there. Fixing:

```
    char** after_tokenization      = _malloc_2D_array (10, 20, 0);
```

Fix _malloc_2D_array (BTW why add underscore to a function name? It serves no purpose...)

```
char** _malloc_2D_array (int rows,
                         int cols,
                         int type)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char** result;

    if (type == 0)
    {
        result = malloc(sizeof(char**) * rows); // BAD
```

Oops! Star counting error here. Let's go back to review some examples.

```
     /* Example */ char* str = malloc (length+1);
     /* Example */ int* array = malloc (sizeof(int) * array_length);
```

In the examples above, the result type has ONE star, and the argument of `sizeof` has NO stars. You allocate a memory for a *type X* and return *a pointer to X*. The type of the pointer to X has one star more than X itself. Fixing:

```
        result = malloc(sizeof(char*) * rows); // GOOD

        for (; i < rows; i++)
        {
            arg_2D_array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * cols); // BAD
```

Same error. Leave place for the null terminator while you're at it. Fixing:
                arg_2D_array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (cols+1)); // BETTER, sizeof(char) == 1 by definition, you can skip it:
                arg_2D_array[i] = malloc(cols+1); // GOOD
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

OK, Back to _strtok (a really bad name for a function by the way).

```
    char*  hold_chars_of_one_group = malloc(sizeof(char*) * strlen(arg_string)); // BAD
```

Same error as above plus one more: you need one more character to hold the null terminator. Fixing:

```
    char*  hold_chars_of_one_group = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(arg_string) + 1); 

    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while (arg_string[i])
    {
        if (arg_string[i] != *arg_delimeter) // BAD, that's not how strtok works
```

There are zero or more characters in `arg_delimeter`, and you are using only the first one (without checking if it exists). You need to check against *each* character in `arg_delimeter` Fixing:

```
        const char* delim;
        int found = 0;
        for (delim = arg_delimiter; *delim && !found; ++delim) // delimiter is spelled this way
          if (*delim == arg_string[i]) found = 1;
        if (!found) // GOOD
```

Continuing:

```
        {
            hold_chars_of_one_group[k] = arg_string[i];
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            after_tokenization[j] = hold_chars_of_one_group; // PROBLEM
```

First, `hold_chars_of_one_group` is not null-terminated. Second, this is not how you copy a string.

```
            hold_chars_of_one_group[k] = '\0';    
            strcpy(after_tokenization[j], hold_chars_of_one_group)
            j++;
            k = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Need to take care of the last token, not delimited by the delimiter.

```
    hold_chars_of_one_group[k] = '\0';
    strcpy(after_tokenization[j], hold_chars_of_one_group);
```

And somehow indicate how many tokens we have. Commonly this is achieved by NULL-terminating the pointer array.

```
    j++;
    after_tokenization[j] = NULL;

    return after_tokenization;
}
```

Ugh! Now test:

```
int main()
{
    char** p = _strtok ("anisha,kaul shizuka;sharma", ",; "); // use different delimiters
    while (*p)  // print all tokens
        printf ("-%s-\n", *p++);
    return 0;
}
```

For completeness, here's the fixed program, uninterrupted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc
#include <string.h> // strlen

char** _malloc_2D_array (int rows,
                         int cols,
                         int type)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char** result;

    if (type == 0)
    {
        result = malloc(sizeof(char*) * rows);
        for (; i < rows; i++)
        {
            result[i] = malloc(cols + 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

char** _strtok (char* arg_string, const char* arg_delimeter)
{
    char** after_tokenization      = _malloc_2D_array (10, 20, 0);
    char*  hold_chars_of_one_group = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(arg_string) + 1);

    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while (arg_string[i])
    {
        const char* delim;
        int found = 0;
        for (delim = arg_delimeter; *delim && !found; ++delim)
          if (*delim == arg_string[i]) found = 1;
        if (!found)
        {
            hold_chars_of_one_group[k] = arg_string[i];
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            hold_chars_of_one_group[k] = '\0';
            strcpy(after_tokenization[j], hold_chars_of_one_group);
            j++;
            k = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    hold_chars_of_one_group[k] = '\0';
    strcpy(after_tokenization[j], hold_chars_of_one_group);
    j++;
    after_tokenization[j] = NULL;

    return after_tokenization;
}

int main()
{
    char** p = _strtok ("anisha,kaul shizuka;sharma", ",; ");
    while (*p)
        printf ("-%s-\n", *p++);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With your code, you need to not only `malloc()` space for `char **after_tokenization`, but also `after_tokenization[j]`. This is because `after_tokenization[j]` is not pointing anywhere in memory, which you need to allocate with `malloc()`.

Instead of:

```
after_tokenization[j] = hold_chars_of_one_group;
```

Which does overwrite the address of `after_tokenization[j]`, you can use this:

```
after_tokenization[j] = malloc(strlen(hold_chars_of_one_group)+1);
```

Which returns a valid pointer to `after_tokenization[j]`, and now the pointer can occupy space because it is pointing somewhere valid in memory. The reason why your code still doesn't work is that you need to copy the contents of `hold_chars_of_one_group` into this pointer waiting to occupy space.

This can be done with `strcpy()` from `<string.h>`:

```
strcpy(after_tokenization[j], hold_chars_of_one_group);
```

Now you have copied the contents into `after_tokenization[j]`.

**Note:** You may need to add a null-byte and the end of `after_tokenization[j]`, otherwise this ends up being undefined behavior.

Another thing to point out is this line:

```
char** after_tokenization = _malloc_2D_array(after_tokenization, 10, 20, 0);
```

Which will lead to problems as `after_tokenization` is not initialized here, and it is awkward for a variable to also be a parameter of the function call.

Also I think I answered a very similar answer before, and I showed some code which does a lot of these things.